# CSS Grid: how to change the flow of a gird?

Tags: css, grid

I haven't been able to find a solution, but it seems it should be simple enough with CSS Grid.

I have a 2x2 grid.  So far, I have only:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
```

My grid looks like this:

A1 A2

B1 B2

How do I change the flow so that it's:

A1 B1

A2 B2

Thank you

Comment: grid-auto-flow: column ?

Comment: As Temani says, please see the documentation: [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Temani and David have said, you can use the [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) property to change how grid items are placed by the grid algorithm. You'll also need to specify your rows:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 50% 50% / 50%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A1</div>
  <div>A2</div>
  <div>B1</div>
  <div>B2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
You can create a code like this.

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.a1{
  background-color: blue;
}
.a2{
backgroud-color:yellow;
}
.b1{
  background-color: green;
}
.b2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="a1">A1</div>
    <div class="a2">A2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="b1">b3</div>
    <div class="b2">b4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't create what OP wants

Comment: Those display in a single column.  I'd like for A1 & A2 to be one column, and B1 & B2 to be a new column.